# Python - Easy and Fast Way to Divide Values in a 2D List by a Single Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example I have a `2D` list of `2x2` dimension stored in a variable `r`.

```
 12    24
 36    48
```

I want to divide every value in the list by `2`. An easy slow way to do this is to iterate through each row and column and divide it by `2`.

```
rows = 2
columns = 2
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(columns):
        r[x][y] = r[x][y]/2
```

Is there an easy and fast way to divide each values in a `2D` list to a specific value other than the manual approach? I tried the code below but it throws an error:

```
 s = r /2
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: To change every cell, you will always have to touch every cell, which will always have linear complexity. You can use `numpy` arrays and utilize your computer's parallel processing capabilities to improve performance, but the asymptotic complexity will remain.

Comment: use numpy. It makes calculations with n-dimensional lists faster and easier without having to use loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/) library to achieve the result you want. it uses vectorization so its the fastest way to do the operation.

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(r) # --> initialize with 2d array
arr = arr / 2 # --> Now each element in the 2d array gets divided by 2
```

---

**For Example:**

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]]) # --> initialize with 2d array
arr = arr / 2 # --> divide by the scalar

print(arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.5 1. ]
 [1.  1.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is even a section in official documentation about nested list comprehensions:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

i.e.

```
>>> r = [[12,24],[36,48]]
>>> [[i/2 for i in a] for a in r]
[[6.0, 12.0], [18.0, 24.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(2D_list)
x=x/2
```